# Solve $\begin{cases}(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2-20=0\\(x-2)^2+(y+1)^2-5=0\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, systems-of-equations, circles

Solve $$\begin{cases}(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2-20=0\\(x-2)^2+(y+1)^2-5=0\end{cases}$$

Should I put $x-1=a$ and $y+1=b$, or just start by removing the parentheses?

Comment: simply expand it should work.

Comment: they are circles. You should get a piece of graph paper and graph them. You have been shown the centers and radii already. I can tell you that there are some points on each circle where both of $x,y$  are integers.  If you have never seen graph paper, or a book with all pages graph paper, print out from  https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph    Finally, if the intersections (or lack of them, or tangency) are not then obvious, more work is required, and may lead to a degree four polynomial in one of $x,y$ for which to find roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2-20=0 \iff x^2+y^2 = 2x-6y+10$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y+1)^2-5=0 \iff x^2+y^2 = 4x-2y$$

So $x = -2y+5$. Now substitute the value of $x$ in one of the equations and you'll find a quadratic equation to solve.

Answer (score 3):

A geometric viewpoint of this:

Suppose $P$ is a point with coordinate $(x, y)$. Let $A = (1,-3)$, $B = (2, -1)$. You see that the first equation just says $|{PA}|^2 = 20$, by the Pythagorean theorem. The second one says $|PB|^2 = 5$. Now draw a circle around $A$ with radius $2\sqrt 5$, and around $B$ with radius $\sqrt 5$. $P$ should lie on the first circle, by the first equation; $P$ should lie on the second circle, by the second equation. Therefore, $P$ lies on the intersection of the two circles. Now by geometrical means, you can determine the coordinates of the intersection point.

Answer (score 3):

Easy to see that $$4^2+2^2=20$$ and $$2^2+1^2=5,$$ which leads to the solution $$(3,1).$$

Now, easy to see that centers $(2,-1)$, $(1,-3)$ and the point $(3,1)$ are placed on the same line,

which says that $(3,1)$ is a touching point of two circles, which gives that it's an unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually tangent, as a diameter of the smaller circle and a radius of the bigger circle coincide. The only intersection with real values is $(3,1)$

.................

[image]

..............................

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By using your idea let $x-2=a$ and $y+1=b$.

Thus, $a^2+b^2=5.$

We'll prove that for there $a$ and $b$ we have $$(a+1)^2+(b+2)^2\leq20,$$
which is $$(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2\leq20.$$
Indeed, by C-S we obtain:
$$(a+1)^2+(b+2)^2=10+2(a+2b)\leq10+2\sqrt{(1^2+2^2)(a^2+b^2)}=20.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b)|(1,2)$, $a^2+b^2=5$ and $a+2b>0,$

which gives only $(a,b)=(1,2)$ or $(x,y)=(3,1).$